# Android BindingAdapter set default behaviour to all TextView

Tags: android, android-binding-adapter

I have a lot of layouts and I would like to have set some default property to 90% of all my `TextViews`.  E.g.

```
@BindingAdapter("sensitive")
fun TextView.sensitive(value: Boolean) {
    if (value)
          visibility = View.GONE //or ViewUtils.BlackMeOut(this)
    else
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Is there any way of doing that without adding:

```
 app:sensitive="@{true}"
```

to 90% of all `TextViews`? Yes, I could create my own `TextView`, but this is not the case. It would be nice to have this in global styles

```
 <style name="SensitiveTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="sensitive">true</item>
    </style>
```

Styles does not seem to support `BindingAdapter`.